# Create tablespace with IMP Oracle10

Tags: import, oracle11g, oracle10g, tablespace

friends,

I have a .dump file of oracle 10G that I have to restore with IMP in oracle 11G. but I don't know how to do it so that you don't put the tables inside the tablespace of the system.

The command I'm using is

imp system/passw file=backup_dpz.dmp fromuser=pepe touser=mario

The problem is that the origin has the tables in the tablespace of system and I want that the destiny has it inside the tablespace of mario.

Thank you